# Preview issue using the camera

Tags: android

By updating my apps, I noticed that the "camera" API was obsolete and that I should now use "camera2".

I installed this [application](https://medium.com/@gauravpandey_34933/how-to-camera2-api-in-android-576fd23650ea) via Android Studio. Regardless of the orientation (vertical or horizontal), the photo is taken correctly. But, because there is a but. It's at the preview level.

When I hold the smartphone vertically, the preview is correct.

If now I tilt it to be horizontal, for a second or two the preview image is still correct, then when the smartphone sensor notices that it is now horizontal, the preview stretches lengthwise . Here is what it gives :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQQkm.jpg)

I can't seem to see what in the code is creating this problem.

Cordially.

Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact, the problem was simply that the smartphone was in "automatic rotation" mode.
I set the mode and everything is back to normal.

Sorry for this request.

Cordially.

Pierre.